# Writing Click Event for a textview within a custom listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on a project where there is a custom listview which has four TextViews in each row.When i click on a textview i want the color of the textview to change.I have tried by doing the code shown below:

```
screenlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final TextView slot1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slot1);;
                    slot1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                slot1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
```

The issue is that it needs two clicks for the color to be set.How do i ensure that i get the color changed on the first click itself?.

EDIT: I have added the adapter code below:

```
public class ScreenListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<ScreensDataModel>  list_screeen;
    Context con;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder vh;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    List<SlotsDataModel> slot_list;

    public ScreenListAdapter(List<ScreensDataModel> list_screeen, Context con) {
        this.con=con;
        this. list_screeen= list_screeen;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  list_screeen.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.screens_view_style, null);
            vh=new ViewHolder();
            vh.screenname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screenname);
            vh.moviename= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moviename);
            vh.slots= (ViewGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.slotview);
            vh.slot1= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot1);
            vh.slot2= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot2);
            vh.slot3= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot3);
            vh.slot4= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot4);



            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
        else
        {
            vh=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.screenname.setText(list_screeen.get(position).getScreenname());
        vh.moviename.setText(list_screeen.get(position).getMoviename());
        slot_list=list_screeen.get(position).list_slots;
        int i=slot_list.size();
        if(i==4)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());
            vh.slot3.setText(slot_list.get(2).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(2).getPrice());
            vh.slot4.setText(slot_list.get(3).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(3).getPrice());
        }
        else if(i==3)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());
            vh.slot3.setText(slot_list.get(2).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(2).getPrice());

        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());


        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
        }


        vh.slot1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vh.slot1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });



        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2B030303"));
        return convertView;

    }
    public class ViewHolder
    {

     TextView screenname;
        TextView moviename;
        ListView slotlist;
        ViewGroup slots;
        TextView slot1;
        TextView slot2;
        TextView slot3;
        TextView slot4;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your adapter you can have listeners for textview.

Comment: In Adapter, implement setOnClickListener for TextView slot 1

Comment: But how do i know which textview of which list row is clicked.slot1  textview is there for all rows.But if i click on the slot 1 textview wouldnt the last row be clicked?.The problem is how do i know which slot 1 textview of which row gets clicked?

Comment: Try to use custom Array list in your adapter . then on the basis of Array list data beans you can easily find out the clicked position of list directly from adapter

Comment: I am using BaseAdapter.Please refer my code above and try to explain how it would work in a baseadapter.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `TextView.setOnClickListener()` in your adapter inside `getView()`. You will have a position of the list item though which you can identify that which item is clicked. Got it?

Comment: I want the color of the textview to change.that textview is there for all rows.How does it know whether it is the textview of the first row or the textview of the second row.Please add code if possible.

Comment: I already mention that you have a position variable inside your getView() function which will identify the row. In other case just post your adapter code,

Comment: I have added the baseadapter code.Still the textview is not setting color.

Comment: Code looks ok to me. Just replace the vh.slot1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); with vh.slot1.setTextColor(Color.RED); to check whether it is working or not

Comment: what should i replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

```
vh.slot1.setOnclickListener...   
  specClickListener spcl=new specClickListener();
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.screens_view_style, null);
            vh=new ViewHolder();
            vh.screenname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screenname);
            vh.moviename= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moviename);
            vh.slots= (ViewGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.slotview);
            vh.slot1= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot1);
            vh.slot2= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot2);
            vh.slot3= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot3);
            vh.slot4= (TextView) vh.slots.findViewById(R.id.slot4);
            vh.slot1.setOnClickListener(spcl);
            vh.slot2.setOnClickListener(spcl);
            vh.slot3.setOnClickListener(spcl);
            vh.slot4.setOnClickListener(spcl);


            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
        else
        {
            vh=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.screenname.setText(list_screeen.get(position).getScreenname());
        vh.moviename.setText(list_screeen.get(position).getMoviename());
        slot_list=list_screeen.get(position).list_slots;
        int i=slot_list.size();
        if(i==4)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());
            vh.slot3.setText(slot_list.get(2).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(2).getPrice());
            vh.slot4.setText(slot_list.get(3).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(3).getPrice());
        }
        else if(i==3)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());
            vh.slot3.setText(slot_list.get(2).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(2).getPrice());

        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
            vh.slot2.setText(slot_list.get(1).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(1).getPrice());


        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            vh.slot1.setText(slot_list.get(0).getTime()+"\n"+slot_list.get(0).getPrice());
        }

    public class specClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public specClickListener (...) {

    }
     @Override public void onClick(View v) {
     v.setbackgrouncolor(Color.Red);
}


}



        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2B030303"));
        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: I have tried the following TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.slot1);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED); inside the item click listener.But i want it to happen on clicking the textview not the list item.